# Custom Route for ServiceStack Razor Content Pages

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

I have the following content page: `/folder/_new.cshtml`

My intention is to have the page accessible through the following url: `/folder/_new`

However it seems that such file name is not mapped to the url. Is there any workaround to make it happen, perhaps by assigning a custom route instead of relying on the pretty-url-by-default feature?

Comment: Why is there one vote to close this question, is this not a valid question? :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pre-defined restriction for not allowing views starting with a `_` prefix to be called directly, the restriction can be removed when you're registering the ServiceStack.Razor plugin with:

```
var razor = new RazorFormat();
razor.Deny.RemoveAt(0);
Plugins.Add(razor);
```